# Missing thing about the meaning of integrating factor problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

I am talking now about (non-)exact equations (or in some languages: equations of the total differential form).

Usually, when there is a problem stated as: "Find a solution $\omega$ for: $(1)\space M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=d\omega$" and it can be quickly found the given equation is not exact, we know we are about to use an integrating factor $\mu(x)$, $\mu(y)$ or something even better.

But this means we are not going to literally "find a solution" for $(1)$, but only for the modified equation: $(2)\space \mu(x)M(x,y)dx+\mu(x)N(x,y)dy=\mu(x)d\omega=d\sigma$. In another words: the original equation $(1)$, in fact, *has no solution*. (Solution for $(2)$ usually does not work for $(1)$ if you try to just plug it in.) The actual thing we find in the process is a factor with some desired type of dependence on some of the variables ($x$, $y$, $xy$, $\frac{1}{xy^2}$, etc.) and a potential corresponding to $(2)$ and the chosen factor.

My question(s) is (are): Is my understanding of the subject correct? If yes, is there some meaning behind the fact that almost all textbooks and websites say "find a solution for (a non-exact/integrable) equation $(1)$" when there isn't any? Is it true there is this habit of calling the solution for $(2)$ to be a solution for $(1)$ as well?

Comment: why do you say: the original equation (1), in fact, has no solution.

Comment: What you're writing in (1) makes absolutely no sense. You're trying to solve $\omega = M\,dx+N\,dy = 0$. You find a nowhere zero function $\mu$ so that $\mu\omega = df$ for some function $f$, and then you say that the level curves $f=C$ give you solutions of $\omega=0$.

Comment: @felasfa When $(1)$ is not exact there doesn't exist any $\omega$ for which its differential is the left-hand side of the equation.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have edited my question so it is clear that I want to find $\omega$. $C$ was indeed superfluous. Most of problems are not stated that way.

Comment: @TedShifrin After a while, now I see my confusion. Your comment was indeed important. I have answered myself. You could check my answer if you were interested. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I - myself - am going to answer your - my - old question. TedShifrin was right.

Your (my) confusion stemmed from the fact that there are two classes of problems solved by a similar method and by the time of asking, you were studying thermodynamics. So your understanding was truly not quite correct.

In thermodynamics, every thermodynamic potential is a Pfaffian *form* that can be written as $(1)$. But this follows from the necessary condition that these potentials are exact. Solution $\omega$ can be constructed by a straightforward integration of the left-hand side,

However, when we solve exact and non-exact *equations* they are always given as

$$ M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0 \tag{3} $$

Your $d\omega$ on the right-hand side of $(1)$ has now no clear meaning. The problems of the form $\dots=0$ are important. Their use is nicely illustrated on [this page](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse11.html).

One of the things is that these equations prescribe some curves in space (like all differential equations after all). In the case of exact equations, we can find a function $F(x,y)$ which has the partial derivatives of $M$ and $N$ and naturally is a constant since $dF$ was set to $0$. And, as we already know from high-school, $F(x,y)=C$ gives us a curve. The slightly confusing thing is that we construct the function $F$ (the *potential of the equation*) by the same process which was used in the integration of forms.

Aaand, in the case of inexact equations... The use of $\mu$ is reasonable because it doesn't touch the solutions of the original problem $(3)$. The expression $\mu(x,y)(M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy)$ is still zero for - at best - the same curves $(x,y)$.

However, here I should be more rigorous: multiplication by an integrating factor is not an equivalent operation and can give the same solutions as for the original problem *on a smaller set*.

It is possible that I miss a general picture here. If there won't be some general revision or specification by someone I will accept this answer.